# How to retrieve angular data into other JS file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile

**This is the angular data below with this url** **https://preshift.bluelid.com/api/Inspections**

```
{
  "@odata.context":"https://preshift.bluelid.com/api/$metadata#Inspections","value":[
    {
      "createdOn":"2014-11-10T15:14:21Z","equipmentName":"8-0010-768 (Hydraulic Excavator)","imageUri":"img/hydraulic_excavator.jpg","id":"561d8731e4b0f25b4aea9890"
    },<br><br>{</br>
      "createdOn":"2014-11-07T19:54:01Z","equipmentName":"8-0000-677 (Track Loader)","imageUri":"img/track_loader.jpg","id":"561ee27cbfc23275f42eec1a"
    }
  ]
}
```

i have to retrieve this angular format into another js file

Comment: What do you mean by retrieve it into another js file?  Is this js file part of your angular framework?

Comment: https://preshift.bluelid.com/api/Inspections   just watch it

Comment: It just seems to be valid JSON object which you can use wherever you want...

Comment: i'm not able to access a single value from that because, i'm beginner for that, i want to access like equipmentName, created on

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular, you use a $http call to get the data.

```
$http.get('https://preshift.bluelid.com/api/Inspections')
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.inspections = response;
    })
    .error(function(){
        console.error('Could not load inspections');
    });
```

When I try to do that on the URL you provided, I get a CORS error. If you can get around that (non angular issue) you'd be able to get your data.

I've made a quick example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/zLguLnv4/1/

Comment: And can you please tell me that name of HTML file and Java Script. what did you gave in that example

Comment: @Pushpendra I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you're asking now. The link shows you the html and javascript code used in the example.

Comment: it showing this error 
--->  Get json data using $http call:
Content from http call: {{ foo }}
Loop trough inspections (hard coded dummy data):
{{ inspection.createdOn }}
{{ inspection.equipmentName }}

Comment: I was presuming you were using angular to retrieve the data. 
Looking at your reply, you're not using angular. 

Are you using any js framework? (like jQuery for example)